# Search data from the master sheet in excel with the dates range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets:
Master Sheet - in which I have all the commission rates of the contractor with the date range; the other sheet is empty where I want to see that which contractor has what commission on my selected dates. I have tried many methods but nothing worked out.

I have tried `Vlookup` as well to search the record with the `IF` condition but it didn`t work out.

Are there any other template which I can use ?

I am sharing the pictures for the reference.

[image: Master]

[image: SearchSheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step: Check if the date your looking for is after Start date (">") and it is before the end date ("<"

```
=IF(AND($D$8>D2,$D$8<E2),"Yes","No")
```

Second Step: Concatenate the Lookup column and answer of Step 1

```
=C2&H2
```

Third Step : Do a Vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP($C$8&"Yes",$B$1:$G$4,5,0)
```

Please see the image attached for better view.

[image]

Comment: Hi Perl

That was awesome and it worked. 
In addition to that, 

1- Is there any way we can hide these cols B and H?
2- In other sheet there will be drop down list for all installer where I can select the list it will popup all the records but dropdown list is duplicating the record.
3- Is this is the proper way to do this because I will have a large number of records in future.

Thanks

Comment: This will work even if you hide the columns. If you have huge data, hi with VBA or powerquery will do it fast.